# Suppress Optimx Warning

Tags: r, optimization, suppress-warnings

I can't seem to suppress the warning `Maximizing -- use negfn and neggr` produced by this function:

```
results_sigma <- optimx(par=sigma_guess, fn=myloglikelihood, lower=0,
                        control=list(dowarn=FALSE,maximize=T),method="L-BFGS-B")
```

I tried both `suppressWarnings()` and `suppressMessages()` but to no avail.

even after setting the logical control dowarn=FALSE.

Comment: It doesn't look like a warning. Rather just an informative message. What happens if you wrap `suppressMessages` around it?

Comment: @BondedDust Tried that and `suppressWarnings()` but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very old question, but:

```
invisible(capture.output( your call ))
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. `invisible` wrapping `capture.output` on the optimx call would return `NULL`, whereas the OP clearly wants results given his `results_sigma <-` approach; but without annoying warnings about using a function call intended for minimizing to maximize (where warnings seem unavoidable). Your approach has value, though perhaps not in this instance.